# Remove duplicates from SQLAlchemy query using set

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a lot of duplicates in the database. To only deliver one (instead of duplicates), I'm trying to use `set`, but it is returning the duplicates too.

```
all_orders = Order.query.filter_by(account_id=account.id).all()
orders = set(all_orders)
```

```
{377, 348, 353, 377, 354, 377, 356, 377, 357, 377, 359, 378, 358, 378, 361, 378, 357, 378, 364, 378, 363, 378, 378, 362, 364, 379, 355, 379, 366, 379, 367, 379, 368, 379, 358, 379, 369, 379, 358, 379, 369, 379, 337, 370, 379, 338, 370, 379, 339, 343, 371, 379, 347, 371, 379, 372, 379, 372, 379, 373, 379, 373, 379, 374, 379, 374, 379, 375, 379, 375, 379, 376, 379, 376, 379, 376, 379, 376, 379, 376, 379, 377, 379, 377, 379, 377, 379, 377, 379, 377, 380, 377, 381, 377, 377, 377, 377}
```

**EDIT**

I am receiving webhook data, and the webhook fired multiple times. I was able to set the sale_id to unique, preventing duplicate data from occurring any further.

Comment: You have to implement `__hash__` and `__eq__`.

Comment: What does `all_orders` look like?

Comment: I don't know much about flask, but I imagine the `Order`s' equality is not based on their `id`, so different instances are considered different even if they have the same `id`. Can you do something like `Order.query.filter_by(account_id=account.id).unique('id').all()` ?

Answer (score 7):

Use the `.distinct()` method in your sql alchemy query to get a set-like list.

```
 ...
 timestamp = calendar.timegm(created.utctimetuple()) # Used to convert time for Intercom   
 orders = Order.query.filter_by(account_id=account.id).distinct()
 print(orders)
 ...
```